# Open JSON usage in SQL Server 2008

Tags: json, sql-server-2008

I have developed some SQL scripts that are run in batch mode. They work perfectly in SQL Server 2017 (my test/development environment). My customer now wants me to port this to SQL Server 2008 (I know should never go backwards but the customer does not want to pay for 2017).

My script looks like:

```
DECLARE @CJSON nvarchar(max)

SELECT @CJSON = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Users\PaulB\desktop\Sched_Data\schedam.txt', SINGLE_CLOB) as j

INSERT INTO Schedules (SchedID, Type, JobNo, TotalHrs, EmployeeID, SchedDate, StartTime, FinishTime)
    SELECT
        SchedID, Type, JobNo, TotalHrs, EmployeeID, SchedDate, StartTime, FinishTime
    FROM
        OPENJSON(@CJSON)
        WITH (SchedID NUMERIC N'$.ID', 
              Type CHAR(15) N'$.Type', 
              JobNo NVARCHAR(5) N'$.Reference', 
              TotalHrs DEC(4,2) N'$.TotalHours', 
              SchedDate DATE N'$.Date',  
              EmployeeID NUMERIC(6) N'$.Staff.ID', 
              Blocks NVARCHAR(MAX) N'$.Blocks' as JSON)
    OUTER APPLY
        OPENJSON(Blocks); 
        WITH (StartTime DATETIMEOFFSET N'$.ISO8601StartTime', 
              FinishTime DATETIMEOFFSET N'$.ISO8601EndTime' )
go
```

The script reads a text file with JSON data and inserts into a table called schedules in this instance. When running the script it gets hung up on the `WITH OPENJSON` statement in SQL Server 2008 but perfect in SQL Server 2017.

What suggestions do you have to make this work (besides upgrading to SQL Server 2017)?

Thanks
Paul

Comment: Well, upgrading to SQL Server 2017 would be the easiest - by far. Otherwise, I guess, you'd have to move the logic of parsing the JSON out into your application and pass in the parsed / relational data to your T-SQL code to store into the tables.

Comment: Considering that the end of support for SQL Server 2008 is few months from now, on July 9, 2019, you should strongly advise your customer to consider upgrading. This isn't 5 minutes job, so you may not need to port your code. Otherwise, just do this in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the powershell to read json convert to database, then insert into sql server 2008, that works too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).